# How to copy items from Documents directory to .app directory in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, directory

I have created a script that saves some files in the Documents directory of my app. Now I need to copy these files into my "application.app" bundle...

How I can do this? Thanks to everyone that can help me.

Comment: I have the downloaded content in the Documents directory, how can I access here?

NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .app bundle is code signed, you can't change its contents afterwards

Comment: With NSFileManager I can't do nothing??

Comment: Its pretty straightforward to move a file from the documents directory to the application directory.  However once you do this you effectively BREAK the digital signature which will prevent the application from ever running again.

The purpose of the digital signature is to verify that the .app bundle has not been tampered with.